# How to load webutil library on Oracle forms for all users on Citrix?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, citrix, oracle-fusion-apps

I have developed an Oracle form which uses webutil functionality. This form works fine when I run it locally. but when I open this form on the Citrix server, it hangs when I try to call webutil library.
This just happens for the Citrix users who are not admin. For the admin users, it works fine because the webutil library is loaded. 
Does anyone know how can I fix this so thatthis library loaded for all users?!

When the control of the program reaches "client_ole2.cretae_object('application.excel');" the program hangs.

Many thanks!

Comment: Which action doesn't work or does nothing works? Probably something to do with rights to execute a tasks, this could be the download of the frmwebutil.jar itself but then probably the frmall.jar won't be downloaded also. Or have you done something for that?

Comment: I have done the changes mentioned on the Oracle Toturial to make webutil works in frmwebutil.jar. and it works locally. Apart from that, I haven't done any changes.

Comment: besides, just when I try to call webutil functions, it doesn't work as it should, otherwise my form works ont he Citrix as well.

Comment: Which functions from webutil do you use? I think it has something to do with access rights. Just try simple functions first like  webutil_file.get_file_separator

Comment: when the control of the program reaches "client_ole2.cretae_object('application.excel');" the program hangs. This is something with the access rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libraries which are installed to be used by Webutil need to be copied to the c:\program files\ java\ jre6 \bin on the Citrix server.

Answer (score 0):

For Forms 10g:

It's usually enough to start your application as the admin once.
The required DLLs will then get copied to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin", and will then be available for every user.

You have to do this once on every one of your Citrix-Servers of course.

With one of the latest patches for Forms 10g, these DLLs will be stored in each users user-directory, so starting it once as an admin isn't necessary anymore (I think this applies to 11g and 12c too).

If this doesn't work, please provide the output of the Java console.

To get better diagnostics, set the following variables in "formsweb.cfg":

```
WebUtilLogging=on
WebUtilLoggingDetail=normal
```

Regards

Markus